# PoiwerPoint auto-updating text boxes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to know if there is a way to link text boxes in PowerPoint in a similar fashion as Excel so that when I update one text box (for instance, changing the title of the presentation), the other linked text boxes will update by themselves. The purpose is to avoid having to go through the whole presentation to change manually every relevant slides. I don't think there is a build in function but I am fairly new to VBA in PowerPoint (have some experience with Excel already). Any input is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can link from PowerPoint to the contents of a cell in an Excel spreadsheet, but you can't link to text in PPT, unfortunately. One possible approach would be to base any slides that need changing on a separate layout or even slidemaster and put the changeable text on the layout/slidemaster. And you could do updates using VBA as well, of course.

Comment: Thank you Steve - it was as I suspected.